# Set UTC timestamp as default value for column in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to use a UTC timestamp as default value for a TIMESTAMP column. We're using DB2 9.5 on Linux

I'm aware of using CURRENT TIMESTAMP, but it provides the local time of the DB2 server (e.g. CEST). In queries you can use

```
SELECT JOB_ID, (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE) as tsp FROM SYSTEM_JOBS;
```

but this does not work in the column definition

```
ALTER TABLE SYSTEM_JOBS ALTER COLUMN CREATED SET DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE

[42601][-104] An unexpected token "ALTER TABLE SYSTEM_JOBS ALTER COLUMN CREAT" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<values>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.23.42
```

I also tried to define a function, that makes the calculation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UTCTIMESTAMP ()
    RETURNS TIMESTAMP
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION

    BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE L TIMESTAMP;
    DECLARE U TIMESTAMP;
    SET L = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
    SET U = L - CURRENT TIMEZONE;

    RETURN U;
    END
;
```

But it's also not accepted in column definition

```
ALTER TABLE SYSTEM_JOBS ALTER COLUMN CREATED SET DEFAULT UTCTIMESTAMP();

[42894][-574] DEFAULT value or IDENTITY attribute value is not valid for column "CREATED" in table "DB2INST1.SYSTEM_JOBS".  Reason code: "7".. SQLCODE=-574, SQLSTATE=42894, DRIVER=4.23.42
```

I'm looking for a method to set the default value in neutral UTC.

Comment: Did you try an AFTER INSERT trigger?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I need something that could be used in the CREATE statement of the table. I have to manage about 200+ tables

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to use expressions in the `DEFAULT` clause. See the description of `default-clause` of the [CREATE TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html).
You can use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger instead, for example, to achieve the same functionality:

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM_JOBS (ID INT NOT NULL, CREATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL) IN USERSPACE1;

CREATE TRIGGER SYSTEM_JOBS_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON SYSTEM_JOBS
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (N.CREATED IS NULL)
SET CREATED=CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE;

INSERT INTO SYSTEM_JOBS(ID) VALUES 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I need something that could be used in the CREATE statement of the table. I have to manage about 200+ tables

Comment: No way. What's the problem with automatic generation of such a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement for whatever number of tables?

Comment: The problem is that I have to set it up for each and every table. Of course that's possible, no question. The `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` default worked perfectly and was easy to set up, until we had to use a DB2 server that has it's locale set to europe/berlin (CEST).

Comment: Just in case. You may set the desired time zone for the instance owner via `TZ` environment variable, and restart the instance, if it’s Linux or Unix. But it is a global setting, so `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` value changes accordingly.